# Cannot install docker machine in ubuntu running in virtual box

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to set up whole docker eco system in ubuntu linux running in virtualbox. I succeed in installing docker engine. But I cannot install docker compose and docker machine. Below are the steps I followed to install docker machine.

```
    $ base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker- machine &&
  sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

I am getting below error

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-machine: line 1: Not: command not found
```

While running the command `docker-machine --version`

Comment: can you show the output (at least the first 4-5 lines) of `cat /usr/local/bin/docker-machine` ?

Comment: root@lenin-VirtualBox:/usr/local/bin# cat docker-machine 
Not Found    root@lenin-VirtualBox:/usr/local/bin#

Comment: @Alexey  Can we install docker machine in Ubuntu running in virtual box

Comment: you definitely can, the question is how you map the ports from your host OS into the virtualbox one, but that's another question. Docker will work in a virtual machine. I was asking to launch `cat /usr/local/bin/docker-machine` with full path, can you do that? And if it's still not found, can you show the output of `uname -s` and `uname -m`

Comment: I think it is my mistake that I am running 32 bit ubuntu linux. That is the problem

Comment: Can you explain me  "how you map the ports from your host OS into the virtualbox one, but that's another question"

Comment: You'd typically use `docker-machine` to launch a dedicated Linux VM in which to run Docker; you generally wouldn't use it from inside an existing Linux VM (or on Linux in general).

Comment: What is the output of uname -s / uname -m on your host? e.g. does the https link you’re trying to curl exist or is returning a 404 (Not Found)? Did you redirect “Not Found” in the /tmp/docker-machine file (would explain why line 1 is “Not” which isn’t a Linux command)?

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall older versions first

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Update the apt package index:

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

Add Docker’s official GPG key:

$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

this 4 lines are one single command. copy paste it.

```
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

pub   4096R/0EBFCD88 2017-02-22
      Key fingerprint = 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid                  Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   4096R/F273FCD8 2017-02-22
```

set up the stable repository. You always need the stable repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

Update the apt package index one more time.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the latest version of Docker CE

```
 sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

test if it is installed

```
 docker --version
```

INSTALL DOCKER COMPOSE

Run this command to download the current stable release of Docker Compose:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
  sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

test it

```
 docker-compose --version
```

Comment: docker —version will bomb out if you’re not part of the docker group.